Issue with javac makefile
I have an issue with the makefile I am doing using java. So:
./bin/fp2/poo/utilidades/TitularInterfaz.class: 
                          ./bin/fp2/poo/utilidades/CodigoPostalInterfaz.class   \
              ./bin/fp2/poo/utilidades/CorreoElectronicoInterfaz.class   \
              ./bin/fp2/poo/utilidades/Excepciones/DniIncorrectoExcepcion.class   \
              ./bin/fp2/poo/utilidades/DniInterfaz.class \
              ./src/fp2/poo/utilidades/TitularInterfaz.java \
/bin/javac $(OPCIONES) ./src/fp2/poo/utilidades/TitularInterfaz.java

It's the part of the makefile which is giving me an error which is the following one:
make: *** No hay ninguna regla para construir el objetivo '-encoding', necesario para 'bin/fp2/poo/utilidades/TitularInterfaz.class'.  Alto.
traduction: "make: *** There is no rule to build the objective '-encoding', needed to 'bin/fp2/poo/utilidade/TitularInterface.class'. Stop."
Knowing that OPCIONES traduces into:  -encoding ISO-8859-1 -g -Xlint -classpath ./bin/ -d ./bin/
So, explaining the whole program has to do more or less the same thing that a bank does, with a bank class (banco.class) and gestor.class (which is the person that can do x movements to the bank accounts.
From what I understand, as a rookie, the error looks like MATE terminal does not take the /bin/javac, nor whereas I would put javac or /usr/bin/javac. Now, I do not understand at all why It does not work on this interface but it does in all the others.
For those that wonder, I have to use a makefile, I would do it on Eclipse, and I have seen that the code is right (I made it on Eclipse and then made the makefile).
I have tried to change the code and remake the makefile as all, but It just does not work there, and knowing that makefile "reads" down to upwards, thus It will not compile any longer.
I have also tried to change destination but It does not work either.

Do not add a backslash at the end of your prerequisites list.  By doing this you are saying that the recipe line (javac ...) is actually part of the list of prerequisites which of course is not true.

Thank you very much, now It is the error 127 (and to anyone seeing the post) you just need to tab.

Dont waste your time with Makefiles. Make and java are not a good match, you'll never get the dependencies right. Just use javac -sourcepath src .... and compile all at once. Or better use Ant/Maven/Gradle

I would use Eclipse If I could choose, but university is university, you know.. But It's cool to learn .

To make clear my comment above, this:
./bin/fp2/poo/utilidades/TitularInterfaz.class: \
                ./bin/fp2/poo/utilidades/CodigoPostalInterfaz.class   \
                ./bin/fp2/poo/utilidades/CorreoElectronicoInterfaz.class   \
                ./bin/fp2/poo/utilidades/Excepciones/DniIncorrectoExcepcion.class   \
                ./bin/fp2/poo/utilidades/DniInterfaz.class \
                ./src/fp2/poo/utilidades/TitularInterfaz.java \
        /bin/javac $(OPCIONES) ./src/fp2/poo/utilidades/TitularInterfaz.java

Should instead be this (note the removal of the last backslash):
./bin/fp2/poo/utilidades/TitularInterfaz.class: \
                ./bin/fp2/poo/utilidades/CodigoPostalInterfaz.class   \
                ./bin/fp2/poo/utilidades/CorreoElectronicoInterfaz.class   \
                ./bin/fp2/poo/utilidades/Excepciones/DniIncorrectoExcepcion.class   \
                ./bin/fp2/poo/utilidades/DniInterfaz.class \
                ./src/fp2/poo/utilidades/TitularInterfaz.java
        /bin/javac $(OPCIONES) ./src/fp2/poo/utilidades/TitularInterfaz.java


Thank you so much, I have been hours long :)

Here's how to think about this error to find the problem.  Make will show the no rule to build target error when (a) you have asked make to build a target, but (b) there is no rule in the makefile to do so.  The only ways to ask make to build a target is either (a) you provided a target name on the command line, or (b) it's a prerequisite of a target.  Since you didn't add --encoding to the make command line it can't be (a) so it must be (b).  So you need to see why make thinks that --encoding is a prerequisite when clearly it should be part of a recipe.  Thus the extra backslash.
